# Changing SVG group stack order on hover?

Tags: javascript, css, animation, svg

I'm working on a little proof of concept to experiment about stacking and triggering animations on hover:

http://dougstewart.io/demos/experiments/svg-interaction/

Something I've yet to figure out is how to shift the z-index of each element group on hover (so yellow would be over orange and green) based on hover. From what I gather that's not an option with CSS but maybe JS? Do I have to just remove the element and move it's markup up?

I've heard it's an option with Velocity.js but I'm not seeing how. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems there's no CSS way to do it at all and it also seems as if it must be manually managed. I ended up adding `data-order="#"` to each `g` and then using this JS to switch the order:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '.hero > g', function() {
  var target = $(this);
  var parent = $(this).parent();

  $(target).remove().appendTo(parent);

}).on('mouseleave', '.hero > g', function() {
  var target = $(this);
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  var spot = $(this).attr('data-order');

  if (spot >= $(this).parent().children().length) {
    $(target).remove().appendTo(parent);

  } else {
    $(target).remove();
    $(parent).children(':nth-child(' + spot + ')').before(target);
  }
});
```

I'll probably clean this up later but it does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

One of the unfortunate features of SVG's version of z-indexing is that it's dependent on DOM order. Elements that occur later in the tree will appear on top of those that appear first.

You'll have to actually re-render your SVG elements in ascending order to get the layering you want.